# How to use Eastern Armenian month names instead of Western Armenian?

Tags: xetex, polyglossia, datetime

When using for example the `datetime` package and printing month names, LaTeX uses Western Armenian month names:

- Յունուար
- Փետրուար
- Մարտ
- Ապրիլ
- Մայիս
- Յունիս
- Յուլիս
- Օգոստոս
- Սեպտեմբեր
- Հոկտեմբեր
- Նոյեմբեր
- Դեկտեմբեր

Example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{armenian}
\newfontfamily{\armenianfont}{DejaVu Sans}

\usepackage{datetime}

\title{Վերնագիր}
\author{Անուն}
\date{\today, \currenttime}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

How can I change these names to Eastern Armenian instead?

- Հունվար
- Փետրվար
- Մարտ
- Ապրիլ
- Մայիս
- Հունիս
- Հուլիս
- Օգոստոս
- Սեպտեմբեր
- Հոկտեմբեր
- Նոյեմբեր
- Դեկտեմբեր

Answer (score 6):

Use this `renewcommand` sequence to set the `datearmenian` variable:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{armenian}
\newfontfamily{\armenianfont}{DejaVu Sans}

\usepackage{datetime}

\renewcommand\datearmenian{\def\today{\number\day~%
 \ifcase 
 \month 
 \or Հունվար
 \or Փետրվար
 \or Մարտ
 \or Ապրիլ
 \or Մայիս
 \or Հունիս
 \or Հուլիս
 \or Օգոստոս
 \or Սեպտեմբեր
 \or Հոկտեմբեր
 \or Նոյեմբեր
 \or Դեկտեմբեր
\fi\space
\number\year}}
\datearmenian

\title{Վերնագիր}
\author{Անուն}
\date{\today, \currenttime}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: You might want to make a feature request on the GitHub site for `polyglossia`: https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia

Comment: @egreg Thanks! https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/79